# Sharpe ratio differs from Tradingview

Tags: programming, portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, risk, quant-trading-strategies

I tried to backtest a simple strategy on TradingView, it made 6 trades with these results:
[image]
Now I want to calculate Sharpe ratio using [definition provided by TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000561856-how-are-strategy-tester-report-values-calculated-and-what-do-they-mean/#:%7E:text=The%20formula%20for%20the%20Sharpe,the%20standard%20deviation%20of%20returns.).
So, my daily returns(`profit_by_days`) equals:

```
2020-11-07    0.45
2020-11-08    0.00
2020-11-09   -0.14
2020-11-10   -0.05
2020-11-11    0.00
2020-11-12    0.00
2020-11-13    0.24
2020-11-14   -0.08
```

Using this Pandas code:

```
sharpe = (profit_by_days.mean() - (2/365))/profit_by_days.std(ddof=0)
```

I get `0.257` Sharpe ratio, while TradingView shows `0.205`.

Why did I get a different result?

Comment: How does this work? In your first table, on november 9 you made 2.81%, but in the profits_by_days on november 9 you have a loss of 14%.

Comment: the profit_by_day is following the cum.profit column I believe, amd it is in decimal, not percenage so it is actually 14bp of profit if i understod correctly, and not 14%

Comment: @noob2 if trade profit is red, then it's loss.

Comment: @Mayeulsgc I think, this column(and profit_by_days) shows `(absolute_profit_of_trade * 100) / capital`. What do you mean by `amd` and `bp`?

Comment: @noob2 still can't figure out what is going wrong. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: In [my experience](https://github.com/DaveSkender/Stock.Indicators/issues/318#issuecomment-761232310) TradingView often uses some creative license and/or untested user-provided formulas in its library.  It's quite possible that the TradingView formula is not correct or has used some alternative assumptions; or, in some cases simply different source data.